# Prepopulate slug field from StackedInline Model Django

Tags: django, model, admin, slug

Here are how my models are setup:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=False, allow_unicode=True)
    language = LanguageField(blank=False, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='')

class Post(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=False, allow_unicode=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And admin.py :

```
class PostInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Post
    extra = 0

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PostInline]
    list_display = ('name', 'slug', 'ordering')
    prepopulated_fields = { 
        'slug': ('name',),
     }

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_category', 'header', 'creation_date', 'number_of_minutes')
    prepopulated_fields = { 'slug': ('header',), }
```

When i am creating Post from Category **StackedInline Posts** in admin, slug does not prepopulate **post header**? I just added `prepopulated_fields = { 'slug': ('header',), }` into `PostInline(admin.StackedInline)` and it works but only when cuurent action is **Add** i saw thah when trying to create **post** from inline model current action is **change** and slug doesn't work from first time!